# Notificação (badge) em múltiplas páginas verificando se existe um elemento em uma delas com javascript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, notificação

Esse script verifica se existe um elemento no html e cria uma notificação (badge do bootstrap) na navbar do site. A notificação só aparece na página em que o elemento que é verificado no html está, preciso colocar na barra de navegação de todas as outras páginas.

```
if ($("#noti").length) {

  var noti = document.createElement("span");
  var icon = document.createElement("i");
  noti.appendChild(icon);

  document.getElementById("ticket").appendChild(noti);

  noti.classList.add("badge");
  icon.classList.add("far");
  icon.classList.add("fa-bell");
};
```

Já tentei usar o iframe com o display:none, mas não funcionou.

(está funcionando mas como eu disse, só aparece na página que o elemento que é verificado está)

Comment: falta explicar como é a sua estrutura de paginas.... *"na navbar do site"* se tem uma navbar, ela já não está "em todas as páginas", ou seja, não é a mesma?

Comment: O projeto é um script, com arquivos .twig, cada página tem seu arquivo twig, por exemplo: ticket.twig, signup.twig, etc... E tem um arquivo onde está a navbar (layout.twig) que é "importando?" para todas as outras páginas automaticamente, eu coloquei esse script que verifica se existe o elemento na tickets.twig, porém só aparece quando eu estou nela, na navbar das outras páginas não aparece. Desculpe se ficou meio confuso, sou novato nesse meio.

Comment: então não seria melhor colocar na navbar que todas as outras paginas já importam?

Comment: Nesse script tem algumas váriaveis prontas, e quando tem uma atualização no status do ticket ele adiciona um elemento automatico no html, eu coloquei um id nesse elemento que quando ter uma atualização ele vai criar o elemento com o id, então o código acima verifica se existe o id, e então adiciona o badge no código, mais especificamente no item tickets da navbar, link de como fica: https://imgur.com/a/1rcWFzh

Comment: Como eu faria para adicionar em todas as navbar que foram importadas?

Comment: é mais ou menos assim que funciona no script: https://codepen.io/Saimon2707/pen/oNEzWYw, esqueci de mencionar que o script que verifica se existe o elemento está na layout.twig, junto com a navbar